# Strange looking dock with Dash-to-Dock

Tags: gnome, dock, appearance, dash-to-dock

I edited configuration files with DConf Editor to make the dock look better in /org/gnome/shell/extension/dash-to-dock, and it was fine, nothing wrong, but some day ago I discovered gnome extension website (https://extensions.gnome.org), which has got awesome extensions, and I noticed dash to dock, I installed it to see if I could make the dock even better, but it started to be strange, it worked but it was strange, sometimes it's normal , other times it's transparent or even half-transparent, like this: [image: Dock screenshot] I uninstalled and removed the extension from https://extensions.gnome.org but it's still strange.
Need help.

Comment: "like this"? Did you mean to attach a screenshot?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, yeah I forgot to add it, now it should be visible

Comment: Which help do you need? Since you removed the extension anyway? I would start by reset my changes in dconf editor.